# Terminal is using the wrong github account and ssh to push and clone

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have two gihub accounts. 1 as my personal github and 1 for my business github. In terminal on my mac when ever i try to push my code to my person github account that has the project... I get a  `Permission to ojandali93/XXX.git denied to RippeApp.` RippeApp is the business github that I have. I want to know how I can switch it from RippeApp to OJandali93 as the github account in terminal. Both accounts have different `ssh` keys.

```
(base) omarjandali@omarsmbpm1max Mobile % git push origin dev
ERROR: Permission to ojandali93/XXX.git denied to RippeApp.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The RippeApp `ssh` key I have is called `RippeApp.pub`
My persona `sssh` key I have setup and connected to github is `ojandali93.pub`

How can I swtich it from `RippeApp` to `OJandali93` in terminal.

I do have a config file:

```
## START GITPOD INTEGRATION
## This section is managed by Gitpod. Any manual changes will be lost.
Include "gitpod/config"
## END GITPOD INTEGRATIOn
```

Comment: It all depends on which key you have _added_. Check `ssh-add -l`.... and make sure that the config you are using is pointing to the right key.

Comment: Why not adding your pro account to your personal repo and only use one account ?